# Can I switch my Eth-1 node and Eth-2 node off while waiting for activation?

Tags: medalla, staking

I setup a Medalla-Geth-Node and a Eth-2 node (Teku) and went through all the steps in the launch pad. My status went from "Deposited" to "Pending" and currently the beaconchain-explorer says "estimated activation in 12 days". Can I power down my computer in the meantime and turn it back on shortly before activation. I dont want to waste electricity. Or will I loose my spot in the activation queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just tried it: Switched it off. I actually missed the activation by 12 hours, but as soon started my node it connected fine and began validating.

I was down 0.15 GoerliETH for ~12 hours of missed attestations.